# Android oval shape 2 colors

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I have a linear layout view whose background I have set to oval shape solid color. So far I have the background as circle. Now I want to achieve same i.e using shape drawable to get a circle with 2 colors. Please see attached.

[image]

Comment: u want to achieve the image u shown right?

Comment: Hi @ZahanSafallwa yes this is what i want to achieve above

Comment: use a `LayerDrawable` with two layers: one is normal blue oval shape and the second is a green oval shape wrapped around the `ClipDrawable`, but honestly why to make it so complex when you can create a custom `Drawable` class where you can draw whatever you want?

Comment: Hi there @pskink can you give me an example customer drawable class

Comment: either create `class MyDrawable extends Drawable {...` or use `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` like this: `class MyShape extends Shape {...`

Answer (score 9):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <gradient
        android:centerX="-1"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:startColor="color1"
        android:endColor="color2"
        />

</shape>
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: Audo Its works, however what I have to do if I want colors to be divided vertically (LEFT/RIGHT) rather than horizontally?

Comment: You can just rotate your view after setting this as background, just add this in xml:

android:rotation="90"

Answer (score 3):

create shape.xml in your drawable folder
shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
<gradient android:startColor="#0000FF" android:endColor="#00FF00"
android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: and add this shape.xml into your view background

Comment: Nice answer,it will look exactly as mentioned in above image by replacing 
android:shape="oval" line with android:shape="ring".
So final xml will look like :-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="ring" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#0000FF" android:endColor="#00FF00"
              android:angle="270"/>
</shape>

Overall your answer is just awesome. @Damini

Answer (score 1):

This might come late, but I had trouble finding good answer so hear my take.

I used a custom drawable to draw the circle and with it a LinearGradient shader which is configured by positions array to have no gradient transition. The gradient line direction is configured in LinearGradient constructor (here it is diagonal).

```
public class MultiColorCircleDrawable extends Drawable {

    private Paint paint;
    private int[] colors;

    public MultiColorOvalDrawable(int[] colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(createShader());
    }

    private Shader createShader() {
        int[] colorsArray = new int[colors.length * 2];
        float[] positions = new float[colors.length * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            int y = i * 2;
            int color = colors[i];
            colorsArray[y] = color;
            colorsArray[y+1] = color;
            positions[y] = 1f / colors.length * i;
            positions[y+1] = 1f / colors.length * (i+1);
        }

        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        int width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
        int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

        return new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height, colorsArray, positions, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (null == paint) {
            init();
        }

        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        int width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
        int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
        canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, (width/2) - strokeWidth, maskPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
    }
}
```